# Loop through a single <td> element - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

i'm new to Laravel. I used @foreach to make a table that gets data from database. I want to make the database value 1 & 0 display as words like Active & Inactive. However, the javascript I made to do it only display the first column(as shown in the output image below). Is there a way to make the script apply to the whole table? Thank you!

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $row->id }}</td>
        <td> {{ $row->name }}</td>
        <td> {{ $row->description }}</td>
        <td id=statust> {{ $row->status }}</td>
        <td id="defaulttt"> {{ $row->default }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{action('DetailTestController@edit',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">EDIT</a></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('DetailTestController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkshow() {
    if (document.getElementById("statust").innerHTML == 1) {
        document.getElementById("statust").innerHTML = "Active";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("statust").innerHTML = "Inactive";
    }
    return;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XDf1.jpg)

Comment: because you are using id, and id is specific for one element only. you should try it with class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd involve a js snippet for this purpose. In fact, you can simply just use a ternary in this case.

Blade templates will understand this shorthand if else (ternary operator):

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
    <td> {{ $row->id }} </td>
    <td> {{ $row->name }} </td>
    <td> {{ $row->description }} </td>
    <td> {{ ($row->status == 1) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }} </td>
    <td id = "defaulttt"> {{ $row->default }} </td>
    <td><a href="{{action('DetailTestController@edit',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">EDIT</a></td>
    <td>
    <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('DetailTestController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Sidenote for JS: If you're trying to apply multiple instances of actions, `class`es are better suited with this task not `id`s

Answer (score 1):

**put this condition to know your status**

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
 @php
   $status = "";
   @if($row->status == '1')
     $status = "Active";
   @else
     $status = "Inactive";
   @elseif
 @endphp

<td>{{ $status }} </td>
@endforeach
```

**Or**

```
<td> {{ ($row->status == 1) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do like that

```
<tbody>
       @foreach ($data as $row)
        <tr>
        <td> {{ $row->id }} </td>
        <td> {{ $row->name }} </td>
        <td> {{ $row->description }} </td>
        <td id = statust> @if($row->status == 1) Active @else Inactive @endif </td>
        <td id = "defaulttt"> {{ $row->default }} </td>
        <td><a href="{{action('DetailTestController@edit',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">EDIT</a></td>
        <td>
        <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('DetailTestController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
          {{csrf_field()}}
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
        </td>
        </tr>

        @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
   @foreach ($data as $row)
     @php
       $status = "";
       @if($row->status == '1')
         $status = "Active"
       @else
         $status = "Inactive"
       @elseif
     @endphp
    <tr>
    <td> {{ $row->id }} </td>
    <td> {{ $row->name }} </td>
    <td> {{ $row->description }} </td>
    <td>{{ $status }} </td>
    <td id = "defaulttt"> {{ $row->default }} </td>
    <td><a href="{{action('DetailTestController@edit',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">EDIT</a></td>
    <td>
    <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('DetailTestController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code only affects on the first row of the table is because you are calling your element through an id instead of class as selector. Id selector is for the element that is unique. Change it to class and on javascript loop through class and apply your logic like so.

> If you are using jQuery:

```
$('.statust').each(function() {
   if($(this).html() ==1){
      $(this).html("Active");
   }else{
      $(this).html("Inactive");
   }  
})
```

> If you are using javascript core:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("statust").forEach(function(e) {
   if(e.innerHTML ==1){
      e.innerHTML = "Active";
   }else{
      e.innerHTML = "Inactive";
   }  
})
```